# Implement a public method that rely on a private property in Swift using protocols

Tags: swift, protocols

I'm building an API that uses ResultBuilder with structs as components and chaining methods as modifiers.
Sometimes different components have the same modifier, e.g.:

```
var resultBuilderContent = {
    Component1()
       .modifier(x: 1)
    Component2()
       .modifier(x: 2)
}
```

I'd like to implement 'modifier' method in a protocol to avoid duplicating the code. But the method relies on internal properties and if I implement it like this:

```
protocol SameModifierProtocol{
    var x: Int { get set }
}
extension SameModifierProtocol{
    public func modifier(x: Int)->SameModifierProtocol{
        var s = self
        s.x = x
        return s
    }
}
public struct Component: SameModifierProtocol{
    var x: Int = 0
    public init(){}
}
// in another module
let c = Component().modifier(x: 1)
```

I get the error: "'modifier' is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level".

If I try to differentiate access levels between two protocols like this:

```
protocol SameModifierProtocol{
    var x: Int { get set }
}

public protocol ReceivingSameModifier{
}
extension ReceivingSameModifier where Self: SameModifierProtocol{
    public func modifier(x: Int)->ReceivingSameModifier{
        var s = self
        s.x = x
        return s
    }
}
```

I get the following error: "Cannot declare a public instance method in an extension with internal requirements".

This is where I stuck. What are my options?

Comment: Remove `x` from your protocol, you have a function in the protocol that takes an Int argument but why do you need to enforce the conforming type to store that in a specific property? Also you can not really enforce this since there is no relation between the property x and the argument x other than having the same name

Comment: @JoakimDanielson x is in a protocol (in both approaches) since the Int value have to be stored somewhere and the function has to have access to the storage. It doesn't matter by which argument name in the function this value is received (x, y, ect.)

Comment: But you shouldn't put the requirement that x has to be stored in a protocol unless it should be public so it can be accessed externally. Internal implementation details is not part of a protocol. I realise now that `modified(x:)`  isn't actually part of the protocol so even more reason to make x public or the problem is a bad design choice and using a protocol isn't the solution here.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson "But you shouldn't put the requirement that x has to be stored in a protocol unless it should be public so it can be accessed externally." This is not true: protocols can be declared internal. I need to expose the method, but keep the storage internal. Clearly my design choice isn't working, I need advice.

Comment: You are misreading me about public here, I mean the property must have the same access level as where you want to use it. I. am trying to give you advice but you seem to have already decided that the property should be not visible even though you need to use it externally.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson To have method exposed and storage internal is a common approach in APIs and in classes' relm it can be implemented straightforwardly, with subclassing. I wanted to use struct to mimic SwiftUI's approach, but it seems that with protocols it is not possible to achieve. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes it is but you are mixing things up, the public API and the internal implementation are two completely different things yet you are trying to enforce a specific internal behaviour via the public API.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes, but what would be your suggestion? I don't see other tools in Swift than protocols, to implement the same method in two structs. But with protocols I fail.

Comment: x needs to be part of the protocol with the same access level as the `modifier` function, that is really all I can suggest with the given information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [this](https://forums.swift.org/t/implement-a-public-method-that-rely-on-a-private-property-in-swift-using-protocols/59712/2) discussion from Swift forum, there are two ways to solve the issue.

First one is straightforward:

```
/// The publically visible capabilities.
public protocol SameModifierProtocol {
  func modifier(x: Int) -> SameModifierProtocol
}
/// The internal requirements on which the default implementation relies.
internal protocol SynthesizedSameModifierProtocolConformance:
  SameModifierProtocol {
    var x: Int { get set }
}
/// The default implementation.
extension SynthesizedSameModifierProtocolConformance {
    public func modifier(x: Int) -> SameModifierProtocol{
        var s = self
        s.x = x
        return s
    }
}

/// Conforms to the public protocol
/// and requests the default implementation from the internal one.
/// Clients can only see the public protocol.
public struct Component: SynthesizedSameModifierProtocolConformance {
    internal var x: Int = 0
    public init() {}
}
```

The second involves an unofficial feature @_spi, that allows to make implementation details unexposed in a public protocol:

```
public protocol SameModifierProtocol {
    @_spi(SameModifier) var x: Int { get set }
}

extension SameModifierProtocol {
    public func modifier(x: Int) -> Self {
        var s = self
        s.x = x
        return s
    }
}

public struct Component: SameModifierProtocol {
    @_spi(SameModifier) public var x: Int = 0
    public init() {}
}
```